# Eclipse C++ in Clearcase vobs: Unresolved inclusion

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, clearcase

I would like to get your thoughts on why I am getting an "`unresolved inclusion`" error for certain `.h` files included as part of my project.

I actually cloned the project from another existing project, by simply copying, pasting and renaming.
Inside the cloned project, which originally had only a `src/` directory, I also created a `tst/` directory and did `right-click->New->Folder` and from the menu, clicked on `Advanced >>` and selected "`Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)`" and browsed to the relevant path under `/vobs` to add the source folder to my project.

Once I did this, the indexer started rebuilding the index, at the end of which I got the above mentioned inclusion errors.

The `.h` files could be located inside a specific folder path under `/vobs`; I first tried including this path by right-clicking on the cloned project and choosing `Properties->Paths` and `Symbols->Includes` to update the include list with the folder path. This didn't resolve the error.

Subsequently, I tried repeating the above procedure for the newly created `tst/` directory from within the project; that didn't resolve the error either.

Not sure what is it that I am missing here.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if those files are there, in your view. '`/vob`' could mean dynamic view, mounted under `/vob`.

I would rather work with a snashot view, which would download those same files on disk (rather than using the MVFS, Multi-Version FileSystem of a dynamic view).

Then, when you are sure the files are there, and `cleartool ls` shows them correctly loaded, you can double-check your inclusion paths, as [mentioned here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1083408/)

> "`unresolved inclusion`" means the file can't be found.
> This means the directory containing it hasn't been specified to CDT or it has been misspelled.
>
> If spelled correctly, normally you would specify the path with `Project --> Properties --> C/C++ General --> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros` etc. on the `Entries` tab as a user entry.

Note that it depends on the type of project.
When you select File --> New -> C/C++ Project you are presented with various options.
The options are for the kind of builder used.
Some, such as Meson, Qt , Arduino and maybe others don't have the option "`Preprocessor`" option.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot use a snapshot view in this case.

Comment: @Vinod OK. Check what `cleartool ls` return though, to make sure those files are available through your dynamic mounted view.

Comment: @VonC I expect that needs build auditing or some other dynamic view-specific functionality...

Comment: @Vinod If you're using /vobs in your includes, are you set in a view on Unix? If Eclipse was started from the GNOME shell, it will not have a view context for the GNOME shell to work in, This could be at least part of the issue. You would have to run "cleartool setview {viewname}" and run Eclipse from the resulting shell. Without doing so, Von's suggestion of using cleartool ls will report "unable to to determine view for '.': not a ClearCase object." since there is no view context for cleartool to resolve

Comment: @BrianCowan Yes, I suspect Unix dynamic view, with `setview`. The kind of setup I don't like ;) Would it work, in general, better with clearmake, using the auditing build you mention (https://flylib.com/books/en/2.615.1.67/1/)?

Comment: Well, since Eclipse C lets you import makefiles, it's possible that this project has a makefile, which lets you use clearmake for build auditing AND winkin. You referred to the CC ANT listener, which is both kind of neat and hardly used. The latter because it's auditing only and not build avoidance. I don't know what you have against Dynamic views, I know the MVFS developers, and they are pretty on top of things.

Comment: @BrianCowan Dynamic views are awesome (so much so that, ironically, Git is trying to emulate them with its VFS for Git: https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit). It is the setview and its spawned subshell that I dislike.

Comment: VFS for git also happens to essentially turn off your ability to work disconnected, turning your Distributed SCM system into a centralized one since it HAS to get to the central server to get the versions to display... The spawned subshell is annoying in a lot of cases, but on Unix, a essentially-chroot shell is the only way to make /vobs actually work and get the RIGHT versions of things.

Comment: @BrianCowan There are tradeoffs for sure, but you still can use it while being (at some times) being disconnected: https://github.com/microsoft/VFSForGit/issues/26#issuecomment-303865437

Answer (score 0):

My **guess** is that you are not set in a view when you start Eclipse. This will prevent resolution of the the absolute "/vobs/..." paths. If you start Eclipse from GNOME (or any other windowed environment) the current working directory of Eclipse is likely your home directory. Without a view context, the /vobs/... paths will not contain any files under source control.

You COULD use /view/myview/vobs/myvob/... in the include paths, but that would mean EVERYONE who would use the project would have to either start your view or create and start an identically named one... And that's just the start of that particular can of worms.

You may want to confirm how Eclipse handles relative paths in the include path. Do they start from the current working directory of Eclipse? The project home directory? Somewhere else? That may give you a safe view-independent way to specify your include paths.

I would try setting a view and starting Eclipse from within the subshell spawned by cleartool setview. Then verify whether the includes are accessible.

Comment: My experience is that I cannot launch Eclipse if my view is not set