# Issue with Eclipse CDT Indexer: Unresolved Inclusion

Tags: eclipse-cdt, clearcase, indexer

I have looked at all the related previous posts, without avail.

I am facing the issue of Eclipse CDT indexer flagging the .h files included in my project specific .h/.cpp files, despite the following:

1. In File->Properties->Paths and Symbols-Includes for the project, the corresponding directory path for the included files have been added
2. In File->Properties->Project References for the project, the corresponding project which has the included files has been selected

I also would like to mention that the directory containing the .h/.cpp files (for which I am getting Unresolved inclusion errors for the included .h files) were originally not part of the project; I added this directory using the File->Import->File System option for the project.

Last but not the least, all of the above mentioned files are reposited in ClearCase Vob.

Appreciate your thoughts

TIA,

Vinod

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing, check if accessing those files through a snapshot view (which loads files on the disk), would change anything.

Accessing them through a dynamic view (as you alluded to with `/vob/...` paths in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65878210/6309)) might trigger a different behavior from Eclipse.